# Async axios request executing before conditions are met

Tags: node.js, post, async-await, axios, try-catch

I have an async function which takes a user object as a parameter, then calls 2 hubspot endpoints using the `await` keyword.

The first is a `GET` request to return a user object from the hubspot database. After checking if the response is equivalent to the object passed as an argument, the second request is triggered if they do not match. This is a `POST` request that updates the hubspot record with the user object argument.

However, whenever running the function with a user object that does not match the hubspot record - the `POST` request appears to have run before the `GET` request, updating the record before the equivalence check happens. This results in the final else block executing, and none of the logs inside the `if (!_.isEqual(hubspotData, updatedUser))` block printing.

```js
async function updateContactDetails(updatedUser) {
    const token = await verifyToken();
    let hubspotData;
    // check existing record with GET request
    try {
        if (!token) throw new Error('Hubspot api token not found.');
        const getUrl = `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/email/${updatedUser.email}/profile`;
        const response = await axios.get(getUrl, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });
        hubspotData = {
            firstname: response.data.properties?.firstname?.value,
            lastname: response.data.properties?.lastname?.value,
            email: response.data.properties?.email?.value,
        };
        console.log(' ~ updateContactDetails ~ updatedUser:', updatedUser);
        console.log(' ~ updateContactDetails ~ hubspotData:', hubspotData);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Hubspot API - fetch error:', e?.response?.data || e);
    }
    if (!_.isEqual(hubspotData, updatedUser)) {
        // update respective record with POST request, if not equal
        console.log("not equal - making post request")
        try {
            console.log(' ~ updateContactDetails ~ updating');
            const updateUrl = `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/${updatedUser.email}`;
            const response = await axios.post(
                updateUrl,
                {
                    properties: [
                        {
                            property: 'firstname',
                            value: updatedUser.firstname,
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'lastname',
                            value: updatedUser.lastname,
                        },
                        {
                            property: 'email',
                            value: updatedUser.email,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    },
                }
            );
            const action = response.data.isNew ? 'create' : 'update';
            console.log(`Contact ${action}d with ${response.config.data}`);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Hubspot API - create/update error:', e?.response?.data || e);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Hubspot contact matches user input');
    }
}
```

Example console output when receiving `updatedUser` with an altered `firstname`. Hubspot data `firstname` should be 'Test2'.

```
 ~ updateContactDetails ~ updatedUser: {
  firstname: 'Test6',
  lastname: 'Test2',
  email: <email>,
}
 ~ updateContactDetails ~ hubspotData: {
  firstname: 'Test6',
  lastname: 'Test2',
  email: <email>,
}
Hubspot contact matches user input
```

I have tried wrapping everything in one try/catch, removing all try/catch blocks, changing the equivalence check to just evaluate if the `firstname` properties (string) are equal on both objects and abstracting the endpoint calls to 2 separate functions.

If I comment out the `POST` request code, the logs inside the if block print if the objects are not equal - so I assume the issue is not with the equivalence check. But as soon as the code is commented back in, the update happens immediately before anything else runs.

Comment: Please share what is being printed to the console. There might be different problems, one of them (as an example) is that `hubspotData` vairable is not defined if call to Hubspot fails or your token is not valid, which will be result is isEqual failure.

Comment: Have added an example log to the original post